# KnpLabs / DoctrineBehaviors Translatable - currentLocale = null

Tags: symfony, doctrine, behavior

Using the trait `\Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\Translation` inside an Entity, I see that the property currentLocale is never setted , so we always obtain the default locale ('en') in all the calls to `$this->translate()`.

If I change this `getDefaultLocale`, all the translations are made correctly, so I think that is no problem with the fallback.

I tried debug the [currentLocaleCallable](https://github.com/touristeye/TEDoctrineBehaviorsBundle/blob/master/Services/CurrentLocaleCallable.php). I see that if I put a "var_dump ($this->container->get('request'));" in the contructor of currentLocaleCallable, the request have a locale to null. And outside the request has the correct locale.It seems that container is not in the scope: request , i don't know how can I get it to work

I post an issue in github https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/issues/71

EDITED

This service is defined in vendor/knplabs/doctrine-behaviors/config/orm-services.yml and is:

```
knp.doctrine_behaviors.reflection.class_analyzer:
    class:   "%knp.doctrine_behaviors.reflection.class_analyzer.class%"
    public:  false

knp.doctrine_behaviors.translatable_listener:
    class:   "%knp.doctrine_behaviors.translatable_listener.class%"
    public:  false
    arguments:
        - "@knp.doctrine_behaviors.reflection.class_analyzer"
        - "%knp.doctrine_behaviors.reflection.is_recursive%"
        - "@knp.doctrine_behaviors.translatable_listener.current_locale_callable"
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }

knp.doctrine_behaviors.translatable_listener.current_locale_callable:
    class:           "%knp.doctrine_behaviors.translatable_listener.current_locale_callable.class%"
    arguments:
        - "@service_container" # lazy request resolution
    public:  false
```

EDIT 2: My composer.json

```
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",        
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "avalanche123/imagine-bundle": "v2.1",
    "raulfraile/ladybug-bundle": "~1.0",
    "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.12.0",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "1.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "psliwa/pdf-bundle": "dev-master",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.1",
    "zendframework/zend-validator": ">=2.0.0-rc2",
    "zendframework/zend-barcode": ">=2.0.0-rc2"
```

Comment: Could you please add your service definition for the CurrantLocaleCallable class to the question?

Comment: okay just wanted to know if you included the provided service definitions and paramters :) Which version of symfony2 (`app/console --version`) and which PHP version (`php -v`) are you using ?

Comment: yes, all the service definitions and their parameters are included, the file is the same that the bundle provides. My symfony version is 2.3.6 and PHP is 5.4.12

Comment: With the same project in symfony 2.3.2 this listener works ok,  but after do a composer update it crashed

Comment: That sounds strange to me - can you provide your `composer.json`?

Comment: composer.json updated